# ssh agent with loaded key shared across multiple terminal windows

Tags: ssh, nodejs, ssh-agent

I wonder how is it safe if I open terminal and add a key using `ssh-add private-key-file`, and all my other terminals share the same key loaded if I check with `ssh-add -l`. I'm afraid what if I download some nasty nodejs app or an angular app. So, is it possible to change the behaviour that opened terminal window doesn't start agent.

I want to start it manually or if I need I'd like to join existing agent session. How do I do this?

I did this test which makes me unhappy:
Added next line to a server.js

```js
require('shelljs').exec('date && ssh-add -l');
```

Then I opened a terminal session and added a key. Then in VSCode terminal started this

```bsh
auser@auser-VirtualBox:~/testapp$ ssh-add -l
2048 SHA256:somesha256 akey (RSA)
auser@auser-VirtualBox:~/testapp$ node server.js
Wed Jan 30 20:18:47 AEDT 2019
2048 SHA256:somesha256 akey (RSA)
```

I don't want this to happen