# Ubuntu 18.04 how do I create ssh-agent just for 1 terminal application with multiple tabs but not the whole system

Tags: ssh, ssh-agent

I'd like to be able to create ssh agent just for

1. a single terminal window, so that key(s) loaded into that agent are available only in that windows
2. a terminal application running multiple tabs, but not the whole system.

I do not wanna the whole system be able to use keys loaded into the single agent. How I can do this?
Ideally I'd like to be able to have both options. But will be quite happy if I can have even the one.

My problem is that I wanna limit number of things can access my keys. Here's the example which makes me fee bad
[ssh agent with loaded key shared across multiple terminal windows](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1114035/ssh-agent-with-loaded-key-shared-across-multiple-terminal-windows)

Answer (score 1):

SSH agent works by starting a program that binds itself to a Unix socket somewhere in /tmp/ and saving the path to that socket as the environment variable `SSH_AUTH_SOCK`.  It is readable and writable only by your user.

Ultimately, everything that runs as your user has permissions to this socket.  Even if you unset the `SSH_AUTH_SOCK` variable in a particular terminal, it's trivial to find the socket.  If you don't trust a particular program to have access to this socket, you can run it as a different user using sudo like `sudo -u otheruser node server.js`

You can also lock and unlock the agent using `ssh-add -x` and `ssh-add -X`, respectively.

Comment: Thanks for your answer.Unfortunately run as other user doesn't look possible as two many things need to be run as diff user. The VSCode & the app all work using same user. That will be pain to convert.